# bootstrap label borders overlapping

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have  div as below with each having border of 1px defined in labelStyle class.

```
.labelStyle {
    text-align: left; 
    padding: 0px; 
    font-weight: 0px;
    font-size: 8px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}


<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 2px;">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-6 labelStyle">Name</label>
        <label class="col-sm-6 labelStyle">{{name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-6 labelStyle">Number</label>
        <label class="col-sm-6 labelStyle">{{num}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-sm-6 labelStyle">Zip</label>
        <label class="col-sm-6 labelStyle">{{zip}}</label>
    </div>  
</div>
```

When this is rendered since adjacent labels have the border defined for both they look darker.
I want to use border-collapse:collapse sortof functionality here. I tried using border-collapse but it didnt work.
Basically each label should have the top and side borders defined but not the bottom. However the last label should have the bottom border defined.
What is the best way of doing this. These elements are inside DIV and not a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The border-collapse CSS property sets whether cells inside a `<table>`
> have shared or separate borders. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse))

Since you are not dealing with table, you can set `margin-top` to be `-1px` so it will cover the duplicated border that takes 1px (If you change that change `margin-top` also).

```css
div {border: 1px solid black; margin-top: -1px;}
```

```html
<div>bla bla bla 1</div>
<div>bla bla bla 2</div>
<div>bla bla bla 3</div>
<div>bla bla bla 4</div>
<div>bla bla bla 5</div>
```